# Update an image to a view using Layoutinflater

Tags: android, layout

```
ImageView image= 
(ImageView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab1,null).findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

 image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

What is the problem with this inflater?  I have two tabs and this Java class `setContentView` to `tab2.xml` but I want to post my image to `tab1.xml`.  I have created an imageview which has an id of `imageView1` and I want to post this image over there.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.some_view, null);        
ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.some_view_image);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```